# cli/c++ increment operator overloading

Tags: c++-cli, overloading, increment, ref

i have a question regarding operator overloading in cli/c++ environment

```
static Length^ operator++(Length^ len)
{
   Length^ temp = gcnew Length(len->feet, len->inches);
   ++temp->inches;
   temp->feet += temp->inches/temp->inchesPerFoot;
   temp->inches %= temp->inchesPerFoot;
   return temp;
}
```

(the code is from ivor horton's book.)

why do we need to declare a new class object (temp) on the heap just to return it?
ive googled for the info on overloading but theres really not much out there and i feel kinda lost.

Comment: Do you mean `&` when you write `^`?

Comment: Does "cli" means something different in this context from "Command Line Interface", which is what the tag wiki describes it as meaning? I took it to mean the the OP is writing a console program (which is irrelevant but conceivable).

Comment: no, @Henning, the code in the book says ^ - its a handle

Comment: im really new to programming but in the book it is described as part of the .net environment

Comment: @Henning, it's a C++ dialect that has built-in garbage collection. The `^` denotes a pointer to a garbage collected object.

Comment: Ah, so the question was simply mistagged. I have corrected the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way operator overloading is implemented in .NET. Overloaded operator is static function, which returns a new instance, instead of changing the current instance. Therefore, post and prefix ++ operators are the same. Most information about operator overloading talks about native C++. You can see .NET specific information, looking for C# samples, for example this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx
.NET GC allows to create a lot of lightweight new instances, which are collected automatically. This is why .NET overloaded operators are more simple than in native C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you're overloading **POST**-increment operator here. Hence, the original value may be used a lot in the code, copied and stored somewhere else, despite the existance of the new value. Example:

```
store_length_somewhere( len++ );
```

While `len` will be increased, the original value might be stored by the function somewhere else. That means that you might need two different values at the same time. Hence the creation and return of a **new** value.

Comment: thanks, Kornel. but in the book it says that  - quote"Overloading the increment and decrement operators is simpler in C++/CLI than in native C++. As
long as you implement the operator function as a static class member, the same function will serve
as both the prefi x and postfi x operator functions." --- so how can i overload the one that is written as PRE-fix then?

Comment: I will serve as both, but to make sure it behaves well you need to create the result as a new object. Not exactly performance friendly but gets the job done.

Comment: Youu cannot distinguish the pre and post in MC++. There is a big article here on overloading http://www.visualcplusdotnet.com/visualcplusdotnet16.html